# How to create a bar plot in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I've got the following data and want to create a single barplot in R to investigate the differences between different customer types(business and private). How can I write the code? ( the x-axis is year 1, year2,etc; the y axis just denotes different numbers, so that we can see in a certain year, the differences between the numbers of business&private, with coloured bars). Thank you !

```
            year1 year2 year3 year4 year5
business      114    92    22     8     4     
private       368   376    76    32     4
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Usually it is best to first look around for the answers via Google. The problem that you describe is extensively discussed [here (click)](http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/bar.html) (the first hit on `bar plot R`). Does that help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you melt your `data.frame` first, you can use `ggplot`

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

df.melted <- melt(as.matrix(df))
ggplot(df.melted, aes(Var2, value, fill = Var1)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(year1 = c(114L, 368L), year2 = c(92L, 376L), year3 = c(22L, 
76L), year4 = c(8L, 32L), year5 = c(4L, 4L)), .Names = c("year1", 
"year2", "year3", "year4", "year5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("business", 
"private"))
```

Comment: customertyperepair<- structure(list(year1 = c(114L, 368L), year2 = c(92L, 376L), year3 = c(22L, 76L), year4 = c(8L, 32L), year5 = c(4L, 4L)), .Names = c("year1", "year2", "year3", "year4", "year5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("business", "private"))
customertyperepair.melted <- melt(as.matrix(customertyperepair))                                      
ggplot(customertyperepair.melted, aes(Year,Repair, fill = customertype ))+geom_bar(stat="identity")      the error is Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Repair' not found   why is that ...

Comment: Because there is no `Repair` col in the melted df